# Label word wrap in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4, word-wrap

How can the text in a Label control (or a similar control) be wrapped in Flex 4 beta?  In Flex 3 I could use the Text control but this is no longer available in Flex 4.

Comment: The [Text control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html) is still available in Flex 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `maxDisplayedLines` and `lineBreak` properties with spark `Label` component:

```
<s:Label  maxDisplayedLines="{-1}"  lineBreak="toFit"   text="...." />
```

It works with Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<s:SimpleText />`.  From the excellent [Migration Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/flex_4_featuresandmigration.pdf) (p. 75):

> The lightest-weight component of the
>   text primitives. The SimpleText class
>   supports the least number of text
>   features. This class is similar to the
>   Label class, except that it supports
>   multiple lines. It does not support
>   user ineractivity such as selection,
>   editing, or scrolling.

Hope that helps!

Comment: perfect!  and thanks for the link to the migration guide!  very good stuff.

Comment: Note: SimpleText no longer exists. It has been replaced by Label in Flex 4.

Answer (score 0):

[Spark Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) can display multiple lines, which MX Label cannot:

> In Spark Label, three character sequences are recognized as explicit
>   line breaks: CR (`"\r"`), LF (`"\n"`), and CR+LF (`"\r\n"`).
>
> If you don't specify any kind of width for a Label, then the longest
>   line, as determined by these explicit line breaks, determines the
>   width of the Label.
>
> If you do specify some kind of width, then the specified text is
>   word-wrapped at the right edge of the component's bounds, because the
>   default value of the lineBreak style is `"toFit"`. If the text extends
>   below the bottom of the component, it is clipped.
>
> To disable this automatic wrapping, set the lineBreak style to
>   `"explicit"`. Then lines are broken only where the text contains an
>   explicit line break, and the ends of lines extending past the right
>   edge is clipped.